# Clojure destruct map to parse as key parameters

Tags: clojure, maps, keyword, optional-parameters, nested-map

I have a question regarding two functions, one taking a complete map and the other specific keywords like so:

```
(def mapVal
 {:test "n"
  :anotherKey "n"})

(defn functionTest
 [& {:keys [test anotherKey] :or {:test "d" :anotherKey "d"}}]
 (println :test :anotherKey))

(defn mapFunc
 [map]
 (functionTest (get-in map [:test :anotherKey])))
```

The goal would be that all the keys in the parameter map will be passed correctly to the functionTest. Is there anyway this could work? I tried a few things but i just cant get all the keywords and values passed to the functionTest. What i dont want is just the values of the map, it should be passed to the other function with keyword and value.

Answer (score 2):

You're pretty close. A few things should clear it up.

First, when you declare parameters with `[& varname]` that means `varname` will be a list containing all the extra parameters. So you don't need to use that '`&`' here to destructure the input. Instead, you just name which keys you want to have become variables.

Try this:

```
(defn functionTest
 [{:keys [test anotherKey]}]
 (println test anotherKey))
```

And the other problem is using `get-in`. With `get-in` you're defining a "path" through nested data structures with that vector. For example, given:

```
{:first {:a 1 :b 2} :second {:c 3 :d 4}}
```

You could use `get-in` to get the value at `:second` `:c` with this:

```
(get-in {:first {:a 1 :b 2} :second {:c 3 :d 4}} [:second :c])
```

In your case, you don't need to use `get-in` at all. You just need to pass the entire map. The destructuring you defined in `functionTest` will handle the rest. Here is what I did that worked:

```
(defn mapFunc
 [map]
 (functionTest map))
```

I would also suggest you not name the that variable '`map`' since it conflicts with the `map` function.

Answer (score 1):

`get-in` is for accessing nested associative data structures.

```
(def m {:a {:x 1}})
(get-in m [:a :x]) ;;=> 1
```

After you destructure a map those values are in scope and are accessed via symbols. Your example should look like this:

```
(def mapVal
  {:test "n"
  :anotherKey "n"})

(defn functionTest
  [& {:keys [test anotherKey]
      :or {:test "d" :anotherKey "d"}}]
  (println test anotherKey))

(defn mapFunc
  [m]
  (apply functionTest (apply concat (select-keys m [:test :anotherKey]))))


(mapFunc mapVal) ;;=> prints: n n
```

You have to go through this because `functionTest` is accepting bare key value pairs as optional parameters (the ones to the right of the &), as in:

```
(functionTest :test "n"
              :anotherKey "n" )
;;=> Also prints: n n
```

`select-keys` returns a map with only the specified keys:

```
(select-keys mapVal [:test])
;; => {:test "n"}
```

applying `concat` to a map returns a flat seq of keys and values:

```
(apply concat (select-keys mapVal [:test :anotherKey]))
;; => (:test "n" :anotherKey "n")
```

`apply` applies a function to a seq, as though the seq were its argument list:

```
(+ [1 2 3]) ;;=> Error.
(apply + [1 2 3]) ;; => 6
```

As a side note, conventionally in Clojure code, snake-case is preferred to camelCase for most names.